# Pass argument to cURL from script

Tags: bash, curl

I wrote this ABC script:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "x-ha-access: xxx" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"entity_id": "switch.bedroom_tv"}' https://URL/api/services/switch/turn_off
```

which runs properly in the console

```
$ ABC
```

now I need `"switch.bedroom_tv"` to be passed as argument, and modify script:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "x-ha-access: xxx" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"entity_id": "$@"}' https://URL/api/services/switch/turn_off
```

However this won't work if execute in console

```
$ ABC switch.bedroom_tv
```

Comment: Since you haven't provided feedback for this, am deleting the answer, but `curl -X POST -H "x-ha-access: xxx" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"entity_id": "'"$@"'"}' https://URL/api/services/switch/turn_off` should do the trick for you.